# YAML Configuration to Unzip a folder and pick a file

Tags: json, yaml, unzip, backstage

I need to configure YAML such that it returns the file for example,

Here is a good scenario,
definition:
$text: https://github.com/github/rest-api-description/blob/main/descriptions/api.github.com/api.github.com.2022-11-28.json

But Sometimes I have another Scenario where the URL returns be a ZIP file and the json is one of the contents of the ZIP.

How should I configure my YAML now?

Is there a way to unzip it and then select a particular file from it?